# How to list contributors of a git repository?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, github, web-applications

I want to create a web app that lists the contributors of a given git repository.
Can someone please guide me as to where to start? I know about the:

```
git shortlog -s -n
```

but how to integrate it into the web app??

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your backend based on? Add some script where you tried to extract the output.

Comment: I haven't started coding yet. Actually, I can't seem to figure out where to start. I wanted someone to give me a little nudge about the starting point. should I use "git shortlog -s -n" or is there any other way to extract the desired output?

Comment: Yea sure there is a way. but this depends on our backened technologies. You still did not answer this question. What is your backend based on? I think your question is going to be closed or downvoted because you share not codes. Stackoverflow is not made for questions like: "I want to build a app, please guide me".

Comment: I understand what you're saying here. My backend is going to be in node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know `node.js`, if you are going to use `Node.js` as backend, you could use `express` to expose an API to run the git command using [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) module. Using that, you can run terminal commands from `Node.js`.

In `AngularJS` side, you could call this API using `$http` service call and get the data from API.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was extremely helpful.